# Use of setPreferredSize is disregarded by program

Tags: layout, swingx

How do I successfully call setPreferredSize in a method? I'm calling setPreferredSize twice. If I remove the call inside the constructor, the panel doesn't appear at all, whereas it had earlier appeared with the undesired size (500,300). This demonstrates that setPreferredSize is being executed in the constructor, but not in the method of the same class. Note that this is the only issue (as far as I have tested) with my code; there's no unexpected interference outside the code below.

```
...
public abstract class XYGrapher extends JPanel{
    ...
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel contentPane;
    ...
    public XYGrapher() {
        frame = new JFrame("Grapher");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        contentPane.setLayout(new SpringLayout());
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        contentPane.add(this);
    }
    //
    public void drawGraph(int xPixelStart, int yPixelStart, int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh) {
        ...
        contentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pixelsWide, pixelsHigh));
        ...
    }
    //*/
}
```

For reference, this is how XYGrapher eventually gets used:

```
public class GrapherTester extends XYGrapher{
    ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            GrapherTester g = new GrapherTester();
            g.drawGraph(0,0,100,100);
    }
}
```

Comment: The actual problem is doing `contentPane.add(this);` after all setup operations, even when the window has been opened already. It’s pure luck whether a revalidation of the component hierarchy will happen. Further, it might cause flickering. Also, `SpringLayout` is a weird choice for a panel that contains only one component that is supposed to fill the entire panel. In fact, the entire panel is obsolete here. You could simply set your `XYGrapher` as the frame’s content pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue in the meantime. Simply add

```
frame.pack();
```

to the method.